# Web scraping content of ::before using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, web, beautifulsoup, python-requests, screen-scraping

I am quite new to python and tried scraping some websites. A few of em worked well but i now stumbled upon one that is giving me a hard time. the url im using is: https://www.drankdozijn.nl/groep/rum. Im trying to get all product titles and urls from this page. But since there is a ::before in the HTML code i am unable to scrape it. Any help would be very appreciated! This is the code i have so far:

```
try:
    source = requests.get(url)
    source.raise_for_status()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(source.text,'html.parser')
    wachttijd = random.randint(2, 4)
    print("Succes! URL:", url, "Wachttijd is:", wachttijd, "seconden")

    productlist = soup.find('div', {'id':'app'})
    for productinfo in productlist:
        productnaam = getTextFromHTMLItem(productinfo.find('h3', {'class':'card-title lvl3'}))
        product_url = getHREFFromHTMLItem(productinfo.find('a' , {'class':'ptile-v2_link'}))

    # print info
    print(productnaam)
    # Informatie in sheet row plaatsen

    print("Sheet append")
    sheet.append([productnaam])
        #time.sleep(1)


    time.sleep(wachttijd)
    print("Sheet opslaan")
    excel.save('C:/Python/Files/RumUrlsDrankdozijn.xlsx')
    return soup

except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Comment: Have you tried `print(soup)` to examine the actual HTML (rather than what you see in your browser) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The product details for that site are returned via a different URL using JSON. The HTML returned does not contain this. This could easily be accessed as follows:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import openpyxl

url = "https://es-api.drankdozijn.nl/products"

params = {
    "country" : "NL",
    "language" : "nl",
    "page_template" : "groep",
    "group" : "rum",
    "page" : "1",
    "listLength" : "20",
    "clientFilters" : "{}",
    "response" : "paginated",
    "sorteerOp" : "relevance",
    "ascdesc" : "asc",
    "onlyAvail" : "false",
    "cacheKey" : "1",
    "premiumMember" : "N",
}

wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
ws = wb.active
ws.append(['Description', 'Price', 'URL', "Land", "AlcoholPercentage"])

for page in range(1, 11):
    params['page'] = page
    req = requests.get(url, params=params)
    req.raise_for_status()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, 'html.parser')
    data = req.json()

    for product in data['data']:
        land = "unknown"
        alcoholpercentage = "unknown"
        features = {feature["alias"] : feature["value"]["description"] for feature in product['features']}
    
        ws.append([
            product["description"], 
            product["pricePerLiterFormatted"], 
            product["structuredData"]["offers"]["url"],
            features["land"],
            features["alcoholpercentage"]
        ])
    
wb.save('output.xlsx')
```

This gets the first 10 pages of details, starting:

[image: Excel screenshot]

I recommend you `print(data)` to have a look at all of the information that is available.

The URL was found using the browser's network tools to watch the request it made whilst loading the page. An alternative approach would be to use something like Selenium to fully render the HTML, but this will be slower and more resource intensive.

`openpyxl` is used to create an output spreadsheet. You could modify the column width's and appearance if needed for the Excel output.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it seems to be printing the product details like u said!

How am i able to save the name and URL's of the products in an excel sheet for every product on all page now? Should i do something like page = page + 1? or is it a bit more difficult than that?

Comment: It already displays the results from multiple pages. You can use `openpyxl` to write to a spreadsheet. I have updated the answer, hopefully this helps

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! This does exactly what I needed :)  you're a legend!!!

Comment: I also printed the data and copied that into word for easier view. I tried getting the Alcoholpercentage and Country out with **product['alcoholpercentage'] and product['land']** but this didn't work unfortunately. Any idea how i can achieve this? i tried looking if there was a structured text type in front of it but couldn't find anything

Comment: That's a little more complicated as they have a list of different features so it is not directly accessible (you have to first find the feature). The easiest approach is to build up your own dictionary of features from the list and use that. I have updated the answer to show you how